# Populating DropDown List with PHP from MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownbox

I'm trying to bring data from MYSQL Database called `ebms_db`. The table is events and the fields are `Event_ID` and `Event_Name`.

The code I'm using currently to show the `Event_Name` only in the dropdown list is:

```
    <select name="mySelect"> 
        <?php

            include 'db.php';

            $sql = "SELECT Event_Name FROM events";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<select name='Event_Name'>";
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row["Event_Name"].'">'.$row["Event_Name"].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>

        <input type = "submit" name="Search" value="Search">
    </select>
```

Db.Php looks like this...

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "test";
    $dbname = "ebms_db";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, "test", "test", $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        echo "Error";
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

The output shows a combo box with

```
 - '.$row["Events_Name"].'
```

inside it.

Comment: you use while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {... so instead of $row["Event_Name"] use $r["Event_Name"]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate a PHP Dropdown List from MySQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889230/populate-a-php-dropdown-list-from-mysql-database)

Comment: I am using $r["Event_Name"] ... I still get the same result. I changed $row to $r ...

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
       ^^^^ here
    echo '<option value="'.$row["Event_Name"].'">'.$row["Event_Name"].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I changed it to $row in the while loop and in the echo statement. The result is still the same. I get a dropbox with $row["Event_Name"] this written inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php

        include 'db.php';
       // you just fetching here (Event_Name) take all the values from the database or 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<select name='Event_Name'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row["Event_Name"].'">'.$row["Event_Name"].'</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>

    <input type = "submit" name="Search" value="Search">
```

Why are you taking two selects? I just removed one select just beginning above the php tags.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL is deprecated, you should really use something else, if and/or when they remove it your website will be defunct.

Comment: I started coding in PHP and HTML two days ago. So I'm not sure what else I should use. I've gone through many of the solutions on this website but none have helped me.